# R:change column repeated names

Tags: r

I have a data set with many repeated values in one column:

```
A
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
```

…
 How can I change it that it will be like that:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
B1
B2
B3
B4
…
```

Thanks

Comment: Will they always be grouped together like your example, or will there be cases like: `c(A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,A,C)`?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [about Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As you will find in these two links, you should "show your work", and "Questions asking for code must include attempted solutions, why they didn't work". Cheers.

Comment: your example c(A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,A,C) represent best the question case

Comment: What is the expected output for `c(A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,A,C)`?

Comment: Expected output: A1,A2,A3,A4,B1,B2,B3,B4,A5,C1.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `?ave` and `?seq_along` for this:

```
b <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","A","C")

ave(b, b, FUN=function(x)paste0(x, seq_along(x)))
# [1] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" "B1" "B2" "B3" "B4" "A5" "C1"
```

Comment: Thanks. How can the function works on a specific row in a data.frame? e.g., df$name

Comment: @user2676173, try running `b <- as.character(df$name)` first.